# Reactive (or regular) Spring Data Neo4j keeps around relationships

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to assign/save a new list with a single node and expecting it to be in the same state after the save.

Yet, if I return the `Foo` from Neo4j and reassign the list of `Bars`, it maintains a list of all `Bars` that were previously added.

I would expect that previous `Bar` nodes in Neo4j are orphaned and the `Foo` only has a single relationship at any given time.

[image] [image]

How can I tell Spring Data for Neo4j to not "merge" (or whatever you call it) the list and reset the relationships exactly as the list is passed in (with one node).

Any thoughts, advice, or guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Below, you can find a straightforward application that reproduces this problem.

```
@Component
public class RelationshipCommandLineListener implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private FooRepository fooRepository;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        fooRepository.findById("foo").defaultIfEmpty(new Foo("foo", Collections.emptyList()))
            .map(foo -> {
                foo.setBars(List.of(new Bar(System.currentTimeMillis())));

                return foo;
            })
            .flatMap(foo -> fooRepository.save(foo))
            .block();
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    @Bean(ReactiveNeo4jRepositoryConfigurationExtension.DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_MANAGER_BEAN_NAME)
    public ReactiveTransactionManager reactiveTransactionManager(Driver driver, ReactiveDatabaseSelectionProvider databaseNameProvider) {
        return new ReactiveNeo4jTransactionManager(driver, databaseNameProvider);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder()
            .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
            .sources(Main.class)
            .build()
            .run(args);
    }
}
```

Foo, simple holds up to a list of Bars.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Node(primaryLabel = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    String id;

    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Node(primaryLabel = "Bar")
public class Bar {
    @Id
    String id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a relationship in your model `Foo`. Try this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Node(primaryLabel = "Foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    String id;
    
    @Relationship(type = "HAS_BARS", direction = OUTGOING)
    private List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reaching out, this does not have any effect. This simply makes explicit what I already have above. The problem still persists. I was hoping for some sort of "behavior" value on that annotation to not merge relationships, yet there isn't one.

Comment: Ohh okay, It isn't supposed to work that way I think. Let me replicate it